# I don't get all the values of my (int) array from Selection Sort algorithm

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, ubuntu, selection-sort

I'm programming on *Ubuntu 14.04* using the *gcc* compiler.

I am using the *rand();* function to give values to the elements of my array.

( *rand() % 101;* actually, so I don't get values higher than *100* )

Then I want to sort the elements of my array using the 'Selection sort' algorithm, but when I print(f) them out, the first two elements are 0's, even though there are no 0's on my array (most of the time).

Here's my code, please review it, compile it, try it out and guide me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, tam_arreglo;
    time_t t;
    int *a;
    int aux;
    /* Here I'm asking for you to give me the size of the array and store it in tam_arreglo */   
    printf("Introduzca el tamaño del arreglo: \n");
    scanf("%d",&tam_arreglo);

    /* Making my array the size I just asked you */
    int array[tam_arreglo];
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    /* Dynamic random filling of the array */
    printf("El arreglo sin ordenar es: \n");
    a = malloc(tam_arreglo * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0 ; i < tam_arreglo ; i++) {
        a[i] = rand()%101;
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    /* My 'Selection sort' algorithm */
    for(i = 0; i < tam_arreglo; i++) {
        for(j = i+1; j < tam_arreglo; j++) {
            if(a[i] > a[j]) {
                aux = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    /* Here's when I get the error, the first two elements printed are 0's */
    printf("El arreglo ordenado es: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < tam_arreglo; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SO is not a site for code review but for questions.

Comment: You don't see my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not `free()` the array yet, when you will no longer access the memory pointed to buy the pointer, then you call `free()` but never before.

When you access the `a` pointer in the code following `free(a);` there will be garbage because the memory was `free()`'d already.

So, move `free(a)` after the second `for` loop just before `return` and it should work well.

And also, you don't need to use parentheses with `return`, and check the value returned by `scanf()` in case of invalid input, since in that case `tam_arreglo` will be uninitialized and your program will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm now, how could I not see it, what a fast reply, I still have to wait to mark your answer as the correct answer, thank you again, you're a master!

edit: just a question about the etiquette here, should I edit the question to show the correct answer now? or just leave it as it is and just mark your answer as the correct one?